# Object Obect array Json.stringify string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sha

I had a object object array which i used `JSON.stringify()` on i can now see what's in my array but when i do `arr[0]` etc it only outputs one letter.

```
arr = {"hello":"yes","because":"no"}

arr[0] =h
```

I want it to output the whole of the value not just the first letter

My code

```
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    MyProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(MyProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getMyNewsChoicesSuccess, getMyNewsChoicesFail);
    },

    getMyNewsChoicesSuccess = function () {
        //get the news choice by actually fieldname
        var MyChoices = JSON.stringify(MyProperties.get_userProfileProperties().Value);
        $('#NBStest').text(MyChoices);

    },
```

Comment: What is "object object array"

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you copy and paste your real code, because with what you wrote `arr[0]` should be `undefined` and `JSON.stringify(arr)[0]` should be `"{"`.

Comment: You have a terminology problem. There are no arrays in your code. In JavaScript `var foo = {"hello":"yes"};` defines an object. To call it an array is incorrect. It does not have numeric indexes (`0`); it only has named properties (`"hello"`). If you want to get the value `"yes"` you must use the property name, e.g. `foo.hello` or `foo["hello"]` (they are equivalent). If you've converted the object to a string with `JSON.stringify`, then `str[0]` will get the first (0th) character, which will be `{`. If you want to access its properties again, you have to convert it back with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: If this is how you are debugging, might I suggest using a [proper browser](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: how come when i put arr[0] it returns h then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first element from your json string like this

```
JSON.parse(json_str)[0]
```

but in the example you have, the first element is "yes" and its index is "hello" , which means you can't get the first element by the index 0 , however you can get it by its property name like this

```
arr.hello = "yes";
// or
arr['hello'] = "yes";
```

if you want to get the hello which is the key , you have to use this loop

```
for (key in arr)
   console.log(key); 
// it will print 'hello' and then 'because'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its not an array anymore, its a string. arr[0] will return the first letter.

If you want to get the objects from it you need to parse it ( try JSON.parse )

Comment: parse just turns it back to a [object object]

Comment: then what value do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` does exactly what it sounds like.  It turns the javascript object into a string.  So when you do `arr[0]` you are getting the first letter in the string. You need to turn it back into a javascript object if you want to get the actual values.

Comment: if `arr = {"hello":"yes","because":"no"}`, wouldn't `JSON.stringify(arr)[0]` return `"{"`?

Comment: That would be my guess too, but I don't know what other code that has been run to manipulate the new string after he calls the method.